# Searching Activities for text?

Tags: android

I am very new to Android development.  I'm developing an application (if you want to call it that.) that really just displays static text.  It is a guide for people to use at work.  All the text is static.  I've developed many activities that have static text on them.

I'd like to build search functionality in so people don't have to browse using a table of contents.  I know search in android is much more powerful and can search SQLite db & etc, but can it just search various activities in your app?  Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, could you point me in the right direction?  Obviously if you start googling for "search activities for tet", you get a lot of information on "Search Activities."  So as a new Android developer, it is a little frustrating.

I appreciate any help people can give, even if alternatives to what I'm trying to do!

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "can it just search various activities in your app?"?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific.  I'm really new.  As a previous web developer, the activities to me seem like webpages.  Create a new activity when you want a new page to display to the user.  That's how I'm referring to them.  They basically have a bunch of text objects on them that I want to be able to search from.

Answer (score 0):

Since the activities simply contain some text, you already have the text available in one form or another (even if they are just strings compiled into the application).  I would recommend beginning with a search of these strings, or the data source that you are using to build the activities.

Let's assume, for the sake of a brief description, that your text is stored in an array of strings; then you can search these strings to determine which chapter contains the text the user is searching for.  If these chapters were defined in resource files, you might open and search the resource files during the operation.  You will have to implement the specific searching, however, yourself.

There is no automatic index that Android can provide which simply searches through the activities you've defined; the content of any application or screen is too dynamic to index.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I didn't populate from any datasource because this text isn't likely to change I just hard coded the text for the app in text objects.  That is literally what I wanted to search.

Comment: Don't think of an Activity as a web page.  Think of it as a template for a web page.  It should define layout and some generic actions. The content should be plugged in as part of the intent to show it.

If you store the text as an array of strings (like a resource) you can search that array, and plug the text into a `ViewChapterActivity` or some such.